# How do we detect presence of background noise in audio?

Tags: audio, noise, detection

The problem I am facing to solve is detect background hissing or humming sound in any audio stream. The audio stream can be of any type ranging from movies to talk shows.  The background noise is mostly introduced due to issues in recording environment or process of digitization.

In Audacity tool, there is option to remove noise from audio. The process is first to manually single out region of background noise for profiling and then remove profiled noise from the whole file.

Based on this, the initial idea I have is:

1. Single out low level frames in audio.
2. Based on spectrum or some other feature, somehow find out if noise is there in low level frame. Find the profile of the low level frame.
3. If the profiled noise is present in other portions of file, the background noise is detected.

The exact method of steps 2 and 3 are still not clear to me and thats where I need help. Is there any other method for detecting background noise in stream?

Any pointer towards right direction would be highly appreciated.